# jmeter runs for scheduler duration but hangs at end

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, kerberos

I'm running jmeter from the command line with a 300 second duration.

However it rarely finishes the whole job and returns to the command line - I mostly have to cancel it.

This is what I see:

```
C:\dev\tools\apache-jmeter-3.1\bin>jmeter.bat -n -t c:/dev/workspace/docs/JMeter-stress2.jmx -j c:/dev/log/jmeter.log -l c:/dev/log/jmeter-results.csv
Writing log file to: c:\dev\log\jmeter.log
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using c:/dev/workspace/docs/JMeter-stress2.jmx
Starting the test @ Tue Mar 07 15:43:07 GMT 2017 (1488901387136)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445
summary +   1573 in 00:00:23 =   69.0/s Avg:   166 Min:    47 Max:  2175 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 12 Started: 12 Finished: 0
summary +   2135 in 00:00:30 =   71.3/s Avg:   150 Min:    44 Max:  4022 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 12 Started: 12 Finished: 0
summary =   3708 in 00:00:53 =   70.3/s Avg:   157 Min:    44 Max:  4022 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +   2039 in 00:00:30 =   68.0/s Avg:   187 Min:    44 Max: 31024 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 12 Started: 12 Finished: 0
summary =   5747 in 00:01:23 =   69.4/s Avg:   168 Min:    44 Max: 31024 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +   2051 in 00:00:30 =   68.3/s Avg:   168 Min:    41 Max: 30813 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 12 Started: 12 Finished: 0
summary =   7798 in 00:01:53 =   69.2/s Avg:   168 Min:    41 Max: 31024 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +   2296 in 00:00:30 =   76.5/s Avg:   168 Min:    41 Max: 32443 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 12 Started: 12 Finished: 0
summary =  10094 in 00:02:23 =   70.7/s Avg:   168 Min:    41 Max: 32443 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +   1015 in 00:00:30 =   33.8/s Avg:   348 Min:    42 Max: 30255 Err:     5 (0.49%) Active: 12 Started: 12 Finished: 0
summary =  11109 in 00:02:53 =   64.3/s Avg:   184 Min:    41 Max: 32443 Err:     5 (0.05%)
summary +   1880 in 00:00:30 =   62.6/s Avg:   177 Min:    41 Max: 30265 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 12 Started: 12 Finished: 0
summary =  12989 in 00:03:23 =   64.1/s Avg:   183 Min:    41 Max: 32443 Err:     5 (0.04%)
summary +   1499 in 00:00:30 =   50.0/s Avg:   262 Min:    41 Max: 30417 Err:     5 (0.33%) Active: 12 Started: 12 Finished: 0
summary =  14488 in 00:03:53 =   62.2/s Avg:   191 Min:    41 Max: 32443 Err:    10 (0.07%)
summary +   2383 in 00:00:30 =   79.4/s Avg:   148 Min:    42 Max:  3687 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 12 Started: 12 Finished: 0
summary =  16871 in 00:04:23 =   64.2/s Avg:   185 Min:    41 Max: 32443 Err:    10 (0.06%)
summary +   1870 in 00:00:30 =   62.3/s Avg:   172 Min:    41 Max: 30890 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 12 Started: 12 Finished: 0
summary =  18741 in 00:04:53 =   64.0/s Avg:   184 Min:    41 Max: 32443 Err:    10 (0.05%)
summary +    483 in 00:00:35 =   14.0/s Avg:   344 Min:    43 Max: 31082 Err:     3 (0.62%) Active: 1 Started: 12 Finished: 11
summary =  19224 in 00:05:27 =   58.7/s Avg:   188 Min:    41 Max: 32443 Err:    13 (0.07%)
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y
```

The last line of output before I cancel it hangs there indefinitely until I kill it.

The errors are from kerberos, which doesn't have a good reputation in this organisation :( It puts the error logging into the *.csv output file which makes it unusable, but I guess that's a different question. I only mention it because it might be the cause of the hanging.

This is what I see in the end  of the log file. Notice the timestamp of the shutdown message - the log statement before that is the last before it hangs. The errors in the logging stem from connection problems with the kerberos server.

```
2017/03/07 15:48:00 INFO  - jmeter.reporters.Summariser: summary +   1870 in 00:00:30 =   62.3/s Avg:   172 Min:    41 Max: 30890 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 12 Started: 12 Finished: 0 
2017/03/07 15:48:00 INFO  - jmeter.reporters.Summariser: summary =  18741 in 00:04:53 =   64.0/s Avg:   184 Min:    41 Max: 32443 Err:    10 (0.05%) 
2017/03/07 15:48:04 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: Can't execute httpRequest with subject:Subject:
2017/03/07 15:48:07 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping because end time detected by thread: GET get_forecast 5-2 
2017/03/07 15:48:07 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: GET get_forecast 5-2 
2017/03/07 15:48:07 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping because end time detected by thread: GET get_forecast 5-1 
2017/03/07 15:48:07 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: GET get_forecast 5-1 
2017/03/07 15:48:07 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping because end time detected by thread: GET  forecast with history 4-1 
2017/03/07 15:48:07 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: GET  forecast with history 4-1 
2017/03/07 15:48:07 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping because end time detected by thread: POST data/save 2-2 
2017/03/07 15:48:07 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: POST data/save 2-2 
2017/03/07 15:48:07 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping because end time detected by thread: POST forecast/save 3-1 
2017/03/07 15:48:07 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: POST forecast/save 3-1 
2017/03/07 15:48:07 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping because end time detected by thread: GET  forecast with history 4-3 
2017/03/07 15:48:07 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: GET  forecast with history 4-3 
2017/03/07 15:48:07 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping because end time detected by thread: POST data/save 2-1 
2017/03/07 15:48:07 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: POST data/save 2-1 
2017/03/07 15:48:07 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping because end time detected by thread: GET  forecast with history 4-2 
2017/03/07 15:48:07 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: GET  forecast with history 4-2 
2017/03/07 15:48:07 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping because end time detected by thread: GET get_forecast 5-3 
2017/03/07 15:48:07 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: GET get_forecast 5-3 
2017/03/07 15:48:08 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping because end time detected by thread: POST data/save 2-3 
2017/03/07 15:48:08 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: POST data/save 2-3 
2017/03/07 15:48:13 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: Can't execute httpRequest with subject:Subject:
2017/03/07 15:48:13 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping because end time detected by thread: POST forecast/save 3-3 
2017/03/07 15:48:13 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: POST forecast/save 3-3 
2017/03/07 15:48:34 INFO  - jmeter.reporters.Summariser: summary +    483 in 00:00:35 =   14.0/s Avg:   344 Min:    43 Max: 31082 Err:     3 (0.62%) Active: 1 Started: 12 Finished: 11 
2017/03/07 15:48:34 INFO  - jmeter.reporters.Summariser: summary =  19224 in 00:05:27 =   58.7/s Avg:   188 Min:    41 Max: 32443 Err:    13 (0.07%) 
2017/03/07 15:48:34 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping because end time detected by thread: POST forecast/save 3-2 
2017/03/07 15:48:34 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: POST forecast/save 3-2 
2017/03/07 15:51:21 INFO  - jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector: Shutdown hook started 
2017/03/07 15:51:21 INFO  - jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector: Shutdown hook ended
```

**Update 2017-03-10**

Only progress in defining the problem better :(

Why isn't JMeter dumping the connections when I set the connection time-out to 5 secs (connect) + 5 secs (response) on the HTTP request defaults dialog.

Why do I see a max time on the JMeter output of > 30000ms despite the JMeter connection time-out?

Why do I see no stack traces on the server-side? Possibly exceptions getting swallowed maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to lower the simulated load? I see that max response time is around 30 sec., JMeter may fail to stop after the desired because some threads may be blocked waiting for several server responses.

You should also use jvisualvm to monitor JMeter's VM while running the load test to ensure there is enough memory available, as well as look at waiting threads. It may help you to find out the issue.

Comment: Thanks for answering - surely if mem is an issue, I'll get an OutOfMemory exception? I had it running at first with 25 threads in each thread group and all I saw was connection problems, not mem issues. What should I look for then in monitoring memory? Those response times have been troubling me - 30 secs is crazy for a load test. I should try to make it time-out after 10 secs max. Not sure which time-out it is though, on the kerberos server or something I can control client-side.

Comment: I didn't think the profiler would help because I was sure it was something to do with the connections, but I ran it up anyway to see what I could see. Lo and behold! I could see that one thread group wasn't starting. I double checked everything and discovered the start date for the thread group was set to a date far in the future. So that is why JMeter never stopped...  human error, haha

Comment: Glad you could sort it out :)